# Akka: Guarding an async resource

Tags: scala, asynchronous, io, akka, future

While the errors of my SRP ways were corrected [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623784/akka-pattern-for-handling-asynchronous-actions-in-receive), I am still wondering how you would cleanly guarantee single-threaded access to an async resource in akka, such as a file handle. Clearly I don't want to allow multiple read and write operations to be dispatched against it from different threads, but if my actor calls a future based API on that file, that's what would likely happen.

The best pattern I've come up with is this:

```
trait AsyncIO {
  def Read(offset: Int, count: Int) : Future[ByteBuffer] = ???
}

object GuardedIOActor {
  case class Read(offset: Int, count: Int)
  case class ReadResult(data: ByteBuffer)
  private case class ReadCompleted()
}

class GuardedIOActor extends Actor with Stash with AsyncIO {
  import GuardedIOActor._
  var caller :Option[ActorRef] = None

  def receive = {
    case Read(offset,count) => caller match {
      case None => {
        caller = Some(sender)
        Read(offset,count).onSuccess({
          case data => {
            self ! ReadCompleted()
            caller.get ! ReadResult(data)
          }
        })
      }
      case Some(_) => {
        stash()
      }
    }
    case ReadCompleted() => {
      caller = None
      unstashAll()
    }
  }
}
```

But this requirement cannot be esoteric enough for me to roll that kind of kludge. I mean there ought to be plenty of resources that need synchronized access but have an async API. Am I overlooking some named pattern that is common?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790543/using-futures-in-akka-actors) answer and the [pipeTo](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html) method described on the `akka` documentation can help you.

Comment: If I understand the dispatch of futures and what pipeTo correctly, i don't think that helps me. Two Read messages come in, one after the other, both create futures, which are dispatched via the ExecutionContext and could very feasibly execute on two different threads, both trying to access the same file handle at the same time. I mean this is all moot if AsynchronousFileChannel already guarantee synchronized access, but i can't seem to find such a guarantee. And even if does, this only holds if my operation is requires only a single call on the channel

Comment: I understand, I'm thinking if you should really willing to give file operations to multiple thread. What I think is you should have one Actor that serialize access to a file, meaning that only one Actor (and in this way one thread) can access the resource and then have a mail box were the operations are received and executed, probably having an Async IO operation wrapped in a future that can be opened multiple times is a bad design idea in general, as you said this would break the resource access management logic.

Comment: This is an actor that serializes all access to the file. I'm using the future, because the actor shouldn't be blocking the thread while it's doing IO and by using an async IO API, i give up control over which thread the completion comes back on as the reward for not blocking a thread of the actor system

Comment: Sure it is, but you give the opportunity to open multiple Async IO operations, what I meant is that the Actor should serialize the access and operations **also** making sure that one only one thread opens a file. Dan answer is exactly what I had in mind, sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: Your code isn't safe since the callback on that future relies on the actor's internal mutable state (`caller.get`).

Comment: If you look at how caller is used, once it is set, the actor stashes all other messages until caller.get and the ReadCompleted message, i.e. once set the only thread that can access the internal state is the Future's completion. But i admit it's not obvious and Dan Simon's got below makes it much more explicit

Comment: @ArneClaassen, AsynchronousFileChannel is completely thread safe.  Why do you need to serialize the access into it?

Comment: @cmbaxter For the current use case, I do not, but i figure i need to as soon as my operation is multiple calls on AsynchronousFileChannel, such as a write relying on the result of a read, etc. So i'm trying to find a good pattern for such an API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the gist of your solution is not so bad, but you can make your actor behave more like a state-machine by using `context.become`:

```
class GaurdedIOActor extends Actor with Stash with AsyncIO {
  import GuardedIOActor._

  def receive = notReading

  def notReading: Receive = {
    case Read(offset, count) => {
      val caller = sender
      Read(offset,count).onSuccess({
        case data => {
          self ! ReadCompleted()
          caller ! ReadResult(data)
        }
      })
      context.become(reading)
    }
  }

  def reading: Receive = {
    case r: Read => stash()
    case ReadCompleted() => {
      context.become(notReading)
      unstashAll()
    }
  }
}
```

Now your actor has two well-defined states and there's no need for the `var`

Comment: I was avoiding become/unbecome since it added even more boiler plate, but looking at the two implementations, your example is a lot cleaner to read and reason about

Comment: So i guess that is the best pattern. I am still surprised since that's a lot of manual actor management for a what I consider a fairly fundamental use case

Answer (score 1):

I realize this addition is a year late, however this question helped me reason about a similar situation I ran into. The following trait encapsulates the functionality suggested above to reduce boilerplate in actors. It can be mixed in with any actor with Stash. Usage is similar to the `pipeTo` pattern; just type `future.pipeSequentiallyTo(sender)` and your actor will not process messages until `future` has finished and a response has been sent.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.util.Failure
import scala.util.Success

import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.actor.Stash
import akka.actor.Status

trait SequentialPipeToSupport { this: Actor with Stash =>

  case object ProcessingFinished

  def gotoProcessingState() = context.become(processingState)

  def markProcessingFinished() = self ! ProcessingFinished

  def processingState: Receive = {
    case ProcessingFinished =>
      unstashAll()
      context.unbecome()
    case _ =>
      stash()
  }

  final class SequentialPipeableFuture[T](val future: Future[T])(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) {

    def pipeSequentiallyTo(recipient: ActorRef): Future[T] = {

      gotoProcessingState()

      future onComplete {
        case Success(r) =>
          markProcessingFinished()
          recipient ! r
        case Failure(f) =>
          markProcessingFinished()
          recipient ! Status.Failure(f)
      }

      future
    }
  }

  implicit def pipeSequentially[T](future: Future[T])(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) = 
    new SequentialPipeableFuture(future)

}
```

Also available as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/KarlSjostrand/d2e4e8b583c45191b8d0)

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll need to play with it